# Joint Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, product-measure

I am trying to clarify the meaning of a joint pdf.

A collection of random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ that are i.i.d. defined on the space $(\Omega, F, P)$, we define their joint probability as:

$P(X_i\in A_i|i\in \{1,2,...,n\})=P(\cap_i^n X_i\in A_i)=\prod_i^nP(X_i\in A_i)$

If they are only identically distributed then each $X_i$ need not be defined in the same space, only require $P_i(X_i\in A_i)=P_j(X_j\in A_j)$. Then $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is defined on $(\Omega_i\times\Omega_j\times...\times\Omega_n, F_i\otimes F_j\otimes...\otimes F_n,P_i\otimes P_j\otimes...\otimes P_n) $ Then the joint pdf is a product measure defined as:
$P_i\otimes P_j\otimes...\otimes P_n(A_i\times A_j \times...\times A_n)=\prod_i^nP_i(X_i\in A_i)$

How is the probability calculated for the situation where they are independent but not identically distributed?

Is my understanding correct?  I am trying to determine how to calulate the joint probability under different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_i$'s are identically distributed but not necessarily independent you cannot  calculate the joint distribution in terms of their individual distributions.

If they are independent then $P(X_1 \in A_1,X_2 \in A_2,..., X_n \in A_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} P(X_i \in A_i)$.

If they are i.i.d. then $P(X_1 \in A_1,X_2 \in A_2,..., X_n \in A_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} P(X_1 \in A_i)$.

Comment: If random variables are identically distributed do they have to be defined on the same probability space i.e. same P for each $X_i$ or can you have  a different $P_i$ for each $X_i$?

Comment: No, they don't have to be defined on the same space. @NoeVidales

Answer (score 0):

Random variables are the same thing as measurable functions. $P$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$. Independent random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are just $n$ different measurable functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ such that the event
$$
\{\omega\in \Omega\colon X_i(\omega)\in A_i\ \forall\  i=1,\ldots,n\}
$$
has $P$-measure equal to
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i\in A_i),
$$
for all collections of measurable subsets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ of $\mathbb R$.

Whether or not the $X_i$ have the same distribution has no bearing on the definition of independence.